# roman to integer identical functions generating different results

Tags: javascript

I have two solutions to roman to integer in javascript ([leetcode link](https://leetcode.com/problems/roman-to-integer/)), where the first one doesn't work and the second one does. The odd thing is I can't tell any difference between the two. I'm sure I'm missing something, but can't tell.

Here's the [code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/roman-to-integer-lc-k36k5?file=/src/index.js)
Can't tell why romanToInt function doesn't work while romanToInt2 does.

```js
var romanToInt = function(s) {
  //create a map of roman numeral to int value equivalent
  let map = {
    I: 1,
    V: 5,
    X: 10,
    L: 50,
    C: 100,
    D: 500,
    M: 1000
  };
  let total = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
    let curR = s[i];
    let nextR = s[i + 1];
    let cur = map[curR];
    let next = map[nextR];
    if (next) {
      if (cur >= next) {
        total += cur;
      } else {
        total += next - cur;
        i++;
      }
    } else {
      total += cur;
    }
    return total;
  }
};

console.log(romanToInt("III"), 3);
```

```js
var romanToInt2 = function(s) {
  const map = {
    I: 1,
    V: 5,
    X: 10,
    L: 50,
    C: 100,
    D: 500,
    M: 1000
  };

  let total = 0;

  for (let i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
    let curR = s[i];
    let nextR = s[i + 1];
    let cur = map[curR];
    let next = map[nextR];
    if (next) {
      if (cur >= next) {
        total += cur;
      } else {
        total += next - cur;
        i++;
      }
    } else {
      total += cur;
    }
  }
  return total;
};
console.log(romanToInt2("III"), 3);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just checked your code, and its all about the return statement.

The first function `romanToInt` returns the result in the for loop at the first iteration only, while the second function, `romanToInt2` the return is outside of for loop, which means the for loop is executed and then the result is returned,

---

A little hack, when in doubt of two functions exactly same, use any diff checker and paste the code to check the diff. It's easy to tell the difference when visualised. I just put your two functions [here](https://www.diffchecker.com/diff), and it was quick.

Comment: Yup, that explains it. Thank you!